# loglevel-plugin-remote keeps sending the same request to the API continuously

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a React application that uses `loglevel-plugin-remote`, as well as a custom API endpoint to receive the logs for error monitoring.

My log configuration is

```
import log from 'loglevel';
import remote from 'loglevel-plugin-remote';

const customJSON = log => ({
  message: log.message,
  level: log.level.label,
  stacktrace: log.stacktrace
});

if (process.env.REACT_APP_SEND_LOGS === 'true') {
  const apiPath = `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_PATH}/log`;
  remote.apply(log, {
    format: customJSON,
    url: apiPath,
    stacktrace: {
      depth: 10
    }
  });
}

export default log;
```

And an example call is

```
import log from '../utils/logger';
...
  const getUserData = () => {
    return axios({url: userApi, method: 'GET', headers: authContext.authorizationHeaders })
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(error => {
        log.error(error);
      })
  };
```

However, when the log gets called once, it will continually send requests to the API until I finally refresh the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appeared to be with `loglevel-plugin-remote` which only checks to see if there's a `200` success status code response from the API, or else it will keep trying indefinitely.

My API, however, was returning a `201` message which I thought made more sense for *creating* a log entry. But when I changed the response to `200`, I no longer had the issue. It appears to be an open issue with the repo, but hopefully, this helps others if you're seeing the same thing.